# Google Chrome causes system freeze

Tags: google-chrome, freeze

I'm using xubuntu 12.04, but google chrome always causes system freezes while I'm scrolling down a webpage or a drop down box pops out.

It is quite strange that tty1 could not be switched but only my mouse can move.

So I want to know how to find out what's wrong with my chrome browser and fix the bug? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know mutch over xubuntu but would say: run google-chrome in terminal and post the output here (or photo). So we can see what the problem is.

Comment: @Thomas15v Hi, the output is: "Created new window in existing browser session." Nothing more.

Comment: It seems that google chrome is running in the background do "killall chrome; google-chrome"

Comment: Also you can try my solution :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/281377/system-freezes-posibly-because-of-google-chrome/588205#588205

Hope its help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your video driver gets messed up when you scroll the webpage. You can try Using Alt+PrintScreen+"REISUB" (i.e. hold Alt+PrintScreen and press R E I S U B key sequence; B might not work, so you'll have to press reset) to safely restart the system and save the logs. Then you can examine /var/log/kern.log near end of file. There'll likely be some BUG or Oops messages indicating what's going with the driver.

Comment: Thanks. I used SysRq. After pressing 'REISUB' the screen turned off, the light of harddisk and wifi turned down. But the my system cannot reboot automatically. So I have to turn it off by presssing the power button. And how can I analysis the kern.log file?

Comment: You can post it here (via pastebin), so that I could see what's there. (only lines since last [    0.000000] are relevant)

Comment: Thanks! Here is my kern.log fiel:http://sdrv.ms/Z8EtCk. Sorry the file is a bit big that I cannot paste it to pastebin.com. My system  crashes a lot on April 4 & 5. Since April 6, I changed to use the old version kernel, and it is fine by now.

Comment: OK, you have a problem with i915 driver. See lines having "GPU hung" in the log. You'll have to file a bug report about this.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! BTW, could you please tell me how to detect the bug in the kern.log file?

Comment: There's no generic procedure. You just have to read the log from bottom to top to see some indication of a problem like "*ERROR*", "BUG:", "Oops" etc. But there also are some other less common keywords which may tell you something is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help of @Ruslan, I located the bug is my intel i915 video driver on linux kernel 3.2.0-39. Here is some [discussion on ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2128691).

I switched to kernel 3.2.0-37 and it works fine for me by now.

Comment: how do you switch the kernel version? I need to do the same.

Comment: Hi @sureshvv, this question may help you:http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version, the best answer is fine for me. By now I updated the kernel to 3.4.42 and it fixed the bug.

Comment: I  upgraded to 3.5.1 and the problem persists :-(