# System freezes posibly because of google-chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, clementine

I know there are similar questions, but none refer to the way I go about it. Freezes are not regular and I can't reproduce them.

When it does happen, it usually completely freezes for about 10 seconds (sound glitches and no keyboard or mouse moves) after which it comes back for 2-3 seconds and then it repeats. I usually get rid of this by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> and issuing `top` and waiting for a chrome process that uses around 50 to 60 % of the processor to go down (couple of seconds).

Other times the main process eating resources was Clementine (the music player) but that was only around 30%.

After the process goes below 10% I go back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and it doesn't make any more problems.

How to solve this freeze?

Comment: I'm not certain this is exactly what you're looking for - but I have Chromium installed on 12.10 & 13.04 and have not experienced this problems.

Comment: How much RAM do you have and what is your CPU? Chrome is a resource-hungry process, and the default DE (GNOME) is also resource-hungry. You might want to consider installing something lighter.

Comment: @Alex haven't had problems with Chrome on PC. I have 2 GB of RAM and a Intel Dual-Core clocked at 2GHz

Comment: What're you running in Chrome at the time of the freeze?  what sites/applications/flash or java things/etc.?

Comment: @TheLordofTime I wasn't watching a video or something, but there may have been a youtube page in one tab and soundcloud in another. I was using Chrome for at least 4-5 hours straight when that happend.

Comment: @Silviu I'd have to track chrome's threads usage more in Linux, but I believe that for each tab you have chrome launches a thread or sub process.  The longer you have it running, like Firefox, the more RAM and CPU usage it has.  It never hurts to close the browser every couple of hours, so that your system doesn't get overloaded with resources (chromium behaves similarly, but in a more sane way in that it doesn't gobble up CPU and RAM when idle)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar situation, it feels that my system is running better with disabled GPU on Chrome. To do so, add the parameter `--disable-gpu` to the chrome command line:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: system freezes every time I lunch chrome / chromium.

My solution: disable VERTICAL SYNC / REFRESH in GPU settings.
Now it run well, don't need disable hardware acceleration itself.