# Going to google.com/chrome/ freezes ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome, freeze

mouse stops working and then strange Black and white vertical lines appear.
ALT + F2 doesnt work, Alt+ Ctr+ F1 does work, Happens with Firefox, Chromium and The ubuntu Browser, Infact no matter how you try to go to the chrome website this happens.

Comment: Good Afternoon. 

Check my post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281377/system-freezes-posibly-because-of-google-chrome/588205#588205

Hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Intel Video drivers to the latest release (12/2014) fixed this for me!

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads